# How to remove extra parentheses and angular brackets while using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get the info using of NetworkInterface using following command.

```
[root@ip-172-29-45-82 ~]# aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-dd6f6f53 --query Reservations[*].{VpcId:Instances[*].NetworkInterfaces[*].VpcId}
[
    {
        "VpcId": [
            [
                "vpc-38fb075d"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't want extra parentheses and angular brackets.

It should be something like as follows:

```
["VpcId":"vpc-38fb075d"] or [{"VpcId":"vpc-38fb075d"}] or {"VpcId":"vpc-38fb075d"}
```

Is there any way to achieve above output from the above command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it.

I used following command.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-dd6f6f53 --query Reservations[0].{VpcId:Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].VpcId}
```

I just changed * to 0 and its working.

Now the output is

```
{
    "VpcId": "vpc-38fb075d"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Result can be further refined by adding this to the end of your command

```
--output text
```

And the output will be unstructured text:

```
"VpcId": "vpc-38fb075d"
```

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances --region {{ region }} --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[{ID:InstanceId, Name:Tags[?Key==Name].Value,EnvID:Tags[?Key==EnvID].Value, EnvLayer:Tags[?Key==EnvLayer].Value, Type:InstanceType, AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone, State:State.Name, IP:PrivateIpAddress | [0] }]' --output text | sed -e 's,ENVID,,g' -e 's,ENVLAYER,,g' -e 's,NAME,,g' | tr 't' 'n' | sed -e '/^$/d' | awk '{ORS=NR%8?", ":"n";print}' > /tmp/output-text.csv....I am using this in ansible playbook which is ran in jenkins and getting output

Comment: in a sigle line as well as having \t, when I run this command on cli directly there is no \t but inside pipeline not able to remove this \t as well as print each instance on new line

Answer (score 4):

You could run - given that you can't have ENIs in different VPCs:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].VpcId' --output text --instance-ids i-dd6f6f53
```

You can also try nesting your JSON objects - for example, trying to get the name tag from the parent bracket Tags:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress, [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0]]' --output text
```

It is easier to develop the query using the JSON output, then cleaning things up with --output text.